# Integrating on both sides - differential equation - intuition

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, infinitesimals

Let's say I know that a curve passes through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ and has a differential form that can be written as : $P(y)dy = Q(x)dx$. I wish to know the equation of the curve. I know I can solve this 2 ways :

1. Taking the antiderivative on both sides and then calculating the integration constant using the initial condition $y(x_0) = y_0$.
2. Doing both at the same time by integrating both sides using the right integration bounds:

\begin{align} \int_{y_0}^{y} P(y') dy' = \int_{x_0}^{x} Q(x') dx'\end{align}

I know that this second method is right because when $x=x_0$ then $y=y_0$ and both integrals equal $0$. I was wondering however, if I could have a more **visual intuition** for why this equation really is the equation of the curve by thinking of $dx$ and $dy$ as small changes and thinking about these integrals as summations propagating from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x,y)$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that your curve has a parametric representation
$$t\mapsto\bigl(x(t),y(t)\bigr)\quad(t\geq0),\qquad\bigl(x(0),y(0)\bigr)=(x_0,y_0)\ .$$
Then the given condition amounts to
$$P(y(t))\>\dot y(t)=Q(x(t))\>\dot x\qquad(t\geq0)\ .$$
Integrate this from $t=0$ to an arbitrary upper endpoint $T$ and obtain
$$\int_0^T P(y(t))\>\dot y(t)\>dt=\int_0^T Q(x(t))\>\dot x(t)\>dt\qquad(T\geq0)\ .$$
Substituting separately on both sides of the last equation gives
$$\int_{y_0}^{y(T)}P(y)\>dy=\int_{x_0}^{x(T)}Q(x)\>dx\ .$$
Do not write the $(T)$ in the end result,  and you have your recipe.

Answer (score -1):

> "I was wondering however, if I could have a more **visual intuition** for why this equation really is the equation of the curve by thinking of $dx$ and $dy$ as small changes and thinking about these integrals as summations propagating from $(x_0,y_0)$ to $(x,y)$"

is exactly right.  More precisely you should think of them being *infinitesimal* (instead of *small*) changes. Mathematicians used to be terrified of infinitesimals (as witnessed in the other answer) but since 1961 students can feel better about them, because [Abraham Robinson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_Robinson) placed them on solid logical ground.

A technical point: the integral strictly speaking is not exactly an infinite Riemann sum (of infinitesimal terms), but rather the [standard part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_part_function) thereof.

Comment: I still don't understand why \begin{align} \int_{y_0}^{y} P(y') dy' = \int_{x_0}^{x} Q(x') dx'\end{align} is the equation of the curve. Why does a point (x,y) that satisfy $P(y_0+dy)dy + P(y_0+2dy)dy + ... + P(y)dy = Q(x_0+dx)dx + Q(x_0+2dx)+...+Q(x)dx$ lie on the curve?

Comment: If you understand the equality $P(y)dy=Q(x)dx$ then you also understand the equality you mentioned, because it is a *sum* of equalities of the type $P(y)dy=Q(x)dx$.